# How to remove edit row in Kendo Grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid in which when Edit button is clicked, it will redirect to another view. The code is like,

```
<% Html.Kendo().Grid<FlightCenterModels.SalesViewModel>()
    .Name("Sales")
    .TableHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-size:9pt;" })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:480px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model => model.Id(a => a.SalesId))
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .Create(create => create.Action("InsertSaleRecord", "Home"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("SaleRecordsGridAjax", "Home"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateSaleRecord", "Home"))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DeleteSaleRecord", "Home").Data("onUpdateSaleRecord"))
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler").Sync("sync_handler"))
     )
    .Events(events => events
        .Edit("onSalesGridEdit")
     )
    ...
    function onSalesGridEdit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var url = "/Home/EditPage";
        window.location.href = url + "?salesId=" + e.model.SalesId;
    }
```

I know that onSalesGridEdit is run before controller action UpdateSaleRecord. But the edit row still appears in around a second before it redirects to another view. How to make edit not appear at all? Thanks.

Comment: If the edit action is being redirected to another view i.e. not on the page with the grid. why not use a templated command button that does your redirect rather than the default editing mechanism built into the grid.

Comment: How to use templated command button on each grid row? Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: I just wanted to make sure I was understanding the issue before I provided an answer. If what I have said is correct I will provide an answer for you. Have you looked at this for starters: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/custom-command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment.  (Glad this worked for you)

I just wanted to make sure I was understanding the issue before I provided an answer. If what I have said is correct I will provide an answer for you. Have you looked at this for starters: [Custom Command](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/custom-command)